# Express stops queries after 3-4 times

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm creating a React game. In this game, the user can buy card packs. He has an amount of money (called essences) and can chose any type of packs he wants to purchase (mini packs cost 500, normal are 1500 and mega packs cost 3000).

[image]

For every type of pack, I have an onClick button that triggers a function (BuyPack) with a parameter (the cost of the selected pack).

[image: Here is the 500 essences pack.]

⏫Here is the 500 essences pack.

The function then makes an axios call to my express server :

```
const BuyPack = (arg) => {

    let nb = (document.getElementById('essences').innerText) // that obviously sucks lol
    let nbInt = parseInt(nb) // converts innerText to int
    const newSolde = (nbInt - arg) // The calculated amount after the purchase

    // Update visually the amount of essences
    localStorage.setItem('essences', newSolde) 
    document.getElementById('essences').innerHTML = newSolde; // Let's set the new amount

    let datas = {id: localStorage.getItem('id'), typeOfPack: arg}; // id = the user id / arg = 500, 1500 or 3000, it's basically the pack price.

    console.log('datas', datas) // Output : datas {id: '196', typeOfPack: 500}
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/buyPack', {data: datas}) // The axios call that doesn't work as expected

}
```

The axios call is :

```
app.post('/buyPack', function (req, res) {
  const userId = (req.body.data.id)
  const typeOfPack = (req.body.data.typeOfPack)
  console.log(typeOfPack)

  // I make a first request to get the "pre-buy" amount of money
  query("select essences FROM users WHERE id = ?", [userId], (err, rows) => {
    const actualEssences = (rows[0].essences);  // The amount we just got
    // Second query where we update and decrease the amount of money for the user
    query("update users set essences = " + (actualEssences - typeOfPack) + " where id = " + userId)
  })
})
```

For some reason I don't get, after some purchases, my express server just doesn't respond anymore. (the 3000 below are the console.log(typeOfPack).
[image]

Client side, I have no problem, the money is decreasing and I get the console message that I clicked on the pack.
[image]

I've tryied many things, but I really can't see the the issue comes from.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I guess that you've got an unhandled error somewhere. You have `err` parameter but you never use it. At least log it so we know what went wrong

Comment: I put a console.log(err) in my app.js (I guess that's the one you're talking about)
Basically the err is null (and after the 4-5 attempts, the err doesn't log anything at all, as if the 3001 doesnt do anything)

Comment: Your other `query` can fail as well can you should handle the error, but I guess you can have more places like that which can be faulty here

Comment: Now it says :

3000
null
null

Comment: Duplicate from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791358/why-does-axios-post-method-stop-working-after-6-consecutive-post-calls